# Connecting the diffusion coefficient in 2-dimensions and 3-dimensions?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, diffusion, brownian-motion

Say the diffusion coefficient of the concentration of a particle in a fluid in 3-dimensions is $D_{3\textrm{d}}$. Can we estimate the diffusion coefficient of the same particle in the same fluid, in a 2-dimensional layer, $D_{2\textrm{d}}$ from $D_{3\textrm{d}}$? Or is there a fundamental qualitative difference in the dimension change that makes $D_{2\textrm{d}}$ completely different from $D_{3\textrm{d}}$? If so, what are the relevant properties that make $D_{2\textrm{d}}$ different from $D_{3\textrm{d}}$? Is there a formula connecting the two, in terms of other properties of the fluid/particle?

Comment: The diffusion coefficient is independent of dimension. This follows from the definition $D=\langle x(t)^2\rangle/2nt$ where $n$ is the spatial dimension.

Comment: @lemon So $\langle x(t)^2 \rangle$ is proportional to $n$? I know about the equipartition theorem, but maybe other things change when going from 3-dimensions to 2-dimensions, like the effective viscosity.

Comment: Yes. In $n$ dimensions, $\langle x(t)^2\rangle=\langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)^2\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x_i(t)^2\rangle = $n$\langle x_j(t)^2\rangle$ for any $j$.

Comment: @lemon I am aware of this equipartition theorem. But I am worried that the mean deviation along a single dimension, $\langle x_j (t) ^ 2 \rangle$, changes with the number of dimensions, due to a change in effective viscosity, for example. This would make your argument invalid.

Comment: I had been imagining a very thin 3D layer where we effectively ignore a dimension. In a truly 2D system, I suspect you're right that it will differ. Are you able to give more specifics about the system? e.g. is it a Lennard-Jones fluid?

Comment: Very similar to these other questions about 2D vs 3D: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163903/how-do-we-define-capillary-number-in-2d-two-dimensions/163909 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158291/reaction-diffusion-from-kinetic-parameters-in-3d-can-we-infer-their-equivalent/158295

Comment: @lemon Let's say the fluid is water.

Comment: Two-dimensional water will have a very different structure to water in three dimensions, so yes. It wouldn't be hard to run a couple of MD simulations to demonstrate this...

Comment: To answer the original question though: I don't know. My intuition is that any connection would depend on the fluid/solute in a difficult-to-predict way.